# List of identify-my-rock questions to delete [STATUS-COMPLETED]

Tags: support, tag-wiki

Please, vote to delete this list of questions if you have time and you have the privileges to do so (2k).

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/15910/mineral-identification-please-help</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/21300/what-type-of-fossil-or-stone-is-this-found-at-beach-of-the-black-sea</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/15258/please-help-identify</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14938/can-you-help-me-identify-my-rock</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12156/can-anyone-please-help-me-identify-this-rock</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14515/i-need-help-to-identify-this-stone</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14927/please-help-me-identify-the-inside-of-this-stone</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17006/can-you-please-help-me-to-identify-this-thing-i-found-inside-a-rock-in-the-alman</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14350/please-help-me-identify-these-two-rocks</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14859/can-someone-help-me-identify-this-crystal</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14945/can-anyone-help-me-identify-these-rocks-please</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14355/can-someone-help-me-identify-this-rock-please</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/18850/what-kind-of-rock-or-mineral-is-in-my-pic</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14616/identifying-rocks-minerals</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/15290/please-identify-no-origin-known-but-given-to-me-by-a-geologist</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14339/help-identifying-rock</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/15353/need-help-identifying-this-rock-that-my-grandfather-found-in-or-around-hot-sprin</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/22358/identification-of-a-mineral-present-in-a-water-filter</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/21335/what-is-this-egg-shaped-rock</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14474/rock-fossil-id</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/15662/brown-rock-with-hollow-black-interior</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/15677/can-someone-please-help-me-identify-what-this-is-stromatolite-coral-or</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17499/hi-please-could-someone-help-identify-this-rock-received-it-as-a-gift-from-a-fr</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16106/what-kind-of-rock-is-this-white-rock/16107#16107</strike>

<strike>https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/whats-this-stone</strike>

Comment: most of these questions are already closed.

Comment: @MooseSmart We should not only close, we should also delete them

Comment: I deleted a few more from the list, which didn't have any answers.

Comment: I just casted the third (final) delete vote on several of these, if you want to edit the list.