# Id-my-rock questions: close quickly, answer in comments welcoming the new user

Tags: support

Ok so [there are only two remaining questions](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/list-of-identify-my-rock-questions-to-delete) of [id-my-rock](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/id-my-rock). If I type "stack identify my rock" we are no longer appearing as an entry. I hoppe not many users post new questions, but if they do, [this guideliness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/995796) says a question is automatically deleted if:

- Has 30 days
- Has downvotes
- Has no answers

So remember to close quickly [id-my-rock](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/id-my-rock) questions to avoid answers. Don't answer, help and welcome the new user in comments and downvote the question if it has 0 or more votes.

In this way there is no need to waste more time with this deleting and not only closing the questions.